Movie/tv show that involved a cursed dragon?
I remember only bits and pieces about thi so I'll try and list out everything I can remember:

It takes place in a chinatown setting. There were bluish-greenish lights
The main character climbs up a tiny staircase in a crowded alley to meet some mysterious guy to buy something (I think it was a tiny bottle with some liquid but I'm not very sure) I also remember that he was looking for some kind of dragon
He finds what he wants and comes back down. I remember him limping with a cane
He talks to some girl at a bar
He later realizes something was off about the mysterious guy and he was probably the dragon all along
He goes back up to the tiny room to find a dragon flying around and he has to kill it to free it ff the curse or something


Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. Can you approximate when was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Was it live action or animated? Anything at all? For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.
